# Mocking of aggregates with any Java mocking framework

Tags: java, testing, mockito, easymock, powermock

Are there any mocking framework that can do a "full" mocking of every child in an aggregate? For example.

```
final Report report = createMock(Report.class);
expect(report.getReportSides().get(0).getSideGroup().get(1)).andStubReturn(createSomething());
```

I want this call with these indices be mocked without me having to do anything else, and before I start to write some massive testing code... is this possible in any framework, EasyMock, PowerMock, Mockito, etc?

(The class example is a legacy class auto-generated from a customers XML, hence the weird class structure, and the absence of domain service layer).

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question fully; but is the RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS Answer in Mockito (http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) the feature you require?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you know it's strongly advised to not mock values, but with legacy stuff there could be funky stuff.

Anyway the following declaration might do a great part of the job:

```
mock(Report.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

However you seem to have collections in your aggregate `report.getReportSides().get(0).getSideGroup().get(1)`, and due to type generics erasure Mockito or others frameworks cannot infer the runtime type that should be in the collections, so `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` answer will create a mock matching the return type that is read through reflection, and will certainly be a mock of `Object` itself in the case of java collections. So you'll have to deal with it manually.

As a side note, there have been progress for generic types in mockito trunk, it can retrieve more generic information that is embedded in the class, it's clearly not near anything that have runtime introspection (impossible with current versions of Java) but it gets closer to it.
With the upgraded `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` you could do :

```
public interface A<K extends MyKeyType> extends Map<K, MyValueType> {}

deepStubMock.entrySet().iterator().next()
    .getValue().someValueTypeMethod().eventuallyFollowedByAnotherMethod();
```

*EDIT : looks like David answered before me in the comment :)*